# How will this code affect the memory management?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char  a[]="robert";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<a;
}
```

So size of a is now fixed as 7 bits as intuitive. Now if I read something as "qwertyuiop" into 'a' which is larger than 7 bits, it is expected to show overflow. However nothing such happens and it prints the output normally. What's going on here?

Comment: No the size of `a` is seven *bytes*. And C++ have no bound checking. Writing out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*. End of story, really.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Doesn't `char a[]` define an array with the size of the argument?

Comment: @Alex Six letters in the string, plus terminator. An array of seven characters.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You are perfectly right. My question was if there is a difference between `char a[]="robert"` and `char  a[]="robert barateon"`? Doesn't that mean that `a` will have a size of an appropriate string?

Comment: Writing more data into an array than it can hold gives UNDEFINED behaviour.   One possible manifestation is a program crash.  Another possible manifestation is no observable symptom whatsoever.   With suitable hardware support, the program could even electrocute the programmer - and therefore increase the average understanding by surviving programmers of the TRUE meaning of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Writing out of the bounds is an *undefined behaviour*.

In this case looks ok, but what happens if...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char  a[5];
    char  b[7];
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Input:

> kingkong
>   monkeyhunter

Output:

> kingkmonkeyhunter

They are mixed up!

You should be careful with arrays in C++, it could be no visible effects if you try to write out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The operating system (with the help of the processor) defines a region of memory to which your application is allowed to read/write. When you read outside what you are expected, the processor triggers a hardware exception which is caught by your operating system and this triggers the termination of you application.

However, reading outside an array does not necessarily read outside the boundary of your application (you could for example write/read to another variable of your own code). As an example, at the end of your memory region, you usually have the program stack in reverse order.

C++ specifies the reading/writing outside the range of your array as *undefined behavior*. In this case, it may crash or not in a 'random-like' fashion.

Comment: This is quite an old-fashioned answer; we have had virtual memory for many, many decades now. The processor isn't going to be triggering any exceptions here.

Comment: Could you explain further your point? I obviously know about virtual memory, tables management, re-position, etc.. But at my modest knowledge, there is still memory protection, managed by the OS and executed by the CPU.

Comment: The OS manages virtual memory pages, not the processor. Of course the OS is implemented by the processor, but then so is the user's program, so we're not talking about that.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: Virtual memory is to simulate more RAM than the available by moving sections of it to an external storage (usually the HD) . Here I am speaking of Memory Protection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection), used to protect each process from others. In my explanation, I introduce this concept to explain why reading a dangling pointer may or not terminate the application.

Comment: It doesn't need to be "a patent specification" (?) to be truthful. However, I have discovered and concede that virtual address translation is performed in hardware, which I did not know.